# SPSite.RootWeb.AllProperties is null Claims Authentication

Tags: claims-based-auth, spweb, properties

I just created a new WebApplication & Site Collection in sharepoint.

**Note : WebApplication uses Claims Authentication mode, Custom Trusted Identity Provider for my application.**

In powershell when i try to access $site.RootWeb.AllProperties it is returning null

```
$site.RootWeb.AllProperties.Add("a", "1")
```

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>     At line:1 char:21
>
> + $site.RootWeb.AllProperties.Add <<<< ("a","1")
>
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Add:String) [],
>   RuntimeException
>
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Does anyone knows why this occurs?

Comment: This happens only on web applications with claims based authentication and not on integrated authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the site using Elevated Privileges fixed the problem

```
PS C:\windows> [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({$s = get-spsite "http://balajig-01"})
PS C:\windows> $s.RootWeb.AllProperties


Name                           Value
----                           ----- 
vti_associatemembergroup       5
vti_extenderversion            14.0.0.6120
vti_associatevisitorgroup      4
vti_associategroups            5;4;3
vti_createdassociategroups     3;4;5
vti_approvallevels             Approved Rejected Pending\ Review
vti_categories                 Travel Expense\ Report Business Competition G...
vti_associateownergroup        3
vti_defaultlanguage            en-us
```

Thanks anyways

Comment: This would make sense. I'm generally running powershell as site collection or farm admin and don't have a need for that. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

This blog provides a good overview of how to work with the SPWeb property bag while also providing links to MSDN. http://bramnuyts.be/2012/01/10/working-with-spwebs-propertybag/

The root of your problem, it seems, is that you are doing `SPWeb.AllProperties.Add()` instead of `SPWeb.AddProperty()`

Comment: Am getting the same error. See the reflected AddProperty method below 

public void AddProperty(object key, object value)
{
    this.AllProperties.Add(key, value);
}

PS C:\windows> $w.AddProperty("a","1")
Exception calling "AddProperty" with "2" argument(s): "**Access is denied**. (Excep
tion from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
At line:1 char:15
+ $w.AddProperty <<<< ("a","1")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: Hey at least this approach exposed an access denied error which is much easier to troubleshoot :)

Comment: I got this access denied error before also while trying the same in a console application also. Yes really that helped a lot in analysing the issue. Thanks reaaaaally a lot for your help.